# How to attach image in input fields using Php/javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

I am having one form in that input fields are **regno,name,date of birth** etc.

With this input fields i need to attach image along with this input fields how I can do using `PHP/JavaScript`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php) link. It explains the basics.

The most important things is putting the right enctype on the form like this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">
```

and then put a file input in the form:

```
 <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" />
```

The php side is explained at the link

Answer (score 1):

```
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile" value=""/>
    </form>
```